# Cramer-Rao lower bound for biased estimator

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

My question will be of a "What am I doing wrong?" type. Basically it is the continuation of my previous one: [Maximum likelihood estimation for incorrect distribution parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246351/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-incorrect-distribution-parameter).

I have a random variable $X$ which has the normal distribution:
$$
f\left(x|D,\mu_r\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi D}}\exp\left(-\frac{\left(x-\mu_r\right)^2}{2D}\right).
$$
Using the result of $n$ experiments, I am trying to estimate the distribution variance $D$ using the following biased estimator:
$$\hat{D}=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n{\left(x_i-\mu_t\right)^2}.$$
Note, there is $\mu_t$ instead of $\mu_r$, which would have the asymptotically unbiased MLE estimator. In my case the bias is constant and could be written as
$$ \tag{1}
b\left(D\right)=\left(\mu_r-\mu_t\right)^2
$$
The variance of the estimator is
$$ \tag{2}
Var\left(\hat{D}\right) = \frac{2D^2}n \left(1 + \frac{2b}D \right).
$$
For MLE it is just $\frac{2D^2}n$. I've also calculated the Fisher information for my estimator:
$$
I\left(\hat{D}\right) = \frac{n}{2D^2} \left(1 + \frac{2b}D \right).
$$
Again, for MLE it is $\frac{n}{2D^2}$.

Now, I'm trying to check these results using the [Cramér–Rao bound for biased estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Bound_on_the_variance_of_biased_estimators). It says that:
$$
Var\left(\hat{D}\right) \cdot I\left(\hat{D}\right) \ge \left[1+b'\left(D\right)\right]^2.
$$
In my case there should be equality as my estimator is just a biased MLE (*I expect my problem is there*). Also I have $b'(D)=0$ so I must have unity in the right part, but I get
$$
Var\left(\hat{D}\right) \cdot I\left(\hat{D}\right) = \left(1 + \frac{2b}D \right)^2.
$$
What am I doing wrong? Do I really have an ineqality for my estimator?

P.S. Equations (1) and (2) seem to be correct as I've tested them in MATLAB.

Comment: What is $\mu_t$.  For the MLE it would have to be the sample mean.  In which case the bias is unknown.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I ussume the distribution mean to be a-priori known in my model, so I don't need sample mean to estimate $D$. I'm trying to understand, what happens when my a-priori knowledge of distribution mean is wrong. $\mu_r$ is the real mean and $\mu_t$ is the theoretical mean. You can read more about it in my previous question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246351/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-incorrect-distribution-parameter

Comment: If the mean is known the estimator is unbiased because you would use the true mean in the estimate.  If $\mu_r$ is not equal to $\mu_t$  you are not using the MLE.

Comment: Also it seems that this question is essentially the same as the linked question which did not have an answer.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I see that this is not the MLE. But I thought that if it is closely connected to MLE it should also be at the Cramer-Rao lower bound. If this is wrong, how can I calculate the variance of $D$ using the Fisher information and known estimator bias?